# Why can't I import the Tracker class as is done in the Google Analytics Android example code?

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, importerror, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to follow the instructions laid out in the [Google Analytics tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/start) exactly. The code in question comes from:

```
package com.google.samples.quickstart.analytics;

import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
  private Tracker mTracker;

  synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
      GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
  }
}
```

`GoogleAnalytics` is able to import successfully but `Tracker` is not found. A number of other classes appear to be there (*e.g.* `AnalyticsReceiver`, `AnalyticsService`, `HitBuilders`), but there is no `Tracker`.

There are a number of other StackOverflow questions that seem similar but they all relate to not having `com.google.android.gms.analytics` accessible in the project at all and are the result of not adding it properly to `build.gradle`. If `Tracker` and `GoogleAnalytics` are both imported from the same package then I have a harder time seeing why I can import one and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
}
```

And then use Tracker class. It work with me.